# Adding border div pushing other divs out of box

Tags: jquery, layout, css

I am adding a div border on the mouseover of the div, but its pushing other divs out of the box.

I have fixed height and width and have 4 divs for row. finally there are two rows with 8 divs and with fixed height.
When i mouseover any div , it pushes all the divs below it outside the main box.

I tried to increase the height of the main box , but still it pushes out.
can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add transparent border to all div elements. Then in your hover event modify border color/type. That will make divs stay in their position.

Answer (score 2):

Border gets added to the width, so it is making the moused-over element get larger.. this pushes the other divs around..

It is normal behaviour..

You could use `outline` instead of border but it IE has limited support (*IE8 and above*) ..

Answer (score 2):

Border is added to the width of the element. You can try having a border by default with transparent color (or a color that fits with your design), and on mouseover only change the color of the border. Of course you have to subtract the border-width from your fixed height and width.

Comment: Thankks a lot , this site is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the boxes inside the main div to have an absolute position with top/left values.

```
box1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}

box2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 55px;
}
```

.
.
.